# Can't open file under custom folder on my Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm developing a custom plugin for Eclipse and I have a powerpoint file named "extract.ppt" that I want to open through my source code.

When I place the file on my projects root diercotry and use:

```
File file = new File("/extract.ppt");
```

the file opens just fine.

But since im gonna be using a few more files on my application, I thought it would be a good idea to keep them all organised under a folder. So I created a folder named "files" under my main project folder and tried to use:

```
File file = new File("/files/extract.ppt");
```

but I get an error saying the file does not exist. I checked my Eclipse project's folder and the folder "files" as long as the "extract.ppt" are there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Without the leading slash `files/extract.ppt`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
File file = new File(".\\files\\extract.ppt");
```

The ".\\files\\..." is like saying LOOK on current directory IN folder files IN ...

Comment: Tried it. I get the same error still.

Answer (score 0):

You should use relative path:

```
File file = new File("./files/extract.ppt");
```

the `files` folder should be under the project.
Just like .setting or bin folder

Comment: Tried that too and I also get the same error. The folder "files" is under the project folder indeed.

Comment: You sure the file name is .ppt rather than `.pptx`... I can think about nothing else.